# How to access the value of a struct pointer from outsite of the allocatiing function?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, buffer

I use the file where I declare and init a struct

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t * ringBuffer;
    size_t head;
    size_t tail;
    size_t capacity;
    bool full;
} RingBuffer;

static inline void ringBufferInit(RingBuffer* ringBuffer)
{

    ringBuffer = (RingBuffer *) malloc(sizeof(RingBuffer));

    //ringBuffer->ringBuffer = buffer;
    ringBuffer->capacity = 128;
    printf("%d \n", ringBuffer->capacity);
}
```

and the file where I call this function:

```
int main()
{
    testRingBufferPushPopSingle();
}

void testRingBufferPushPopSingle()
{
    RingBuffer ringBuffer;
    ringBufferInit(&ringBuffer);
    size_t a = (ringBuffer->capacity);
    printf("%d \n", a);
}
```

the problem is it seems the pointer is not updated in the main function because the program prints

128

2125407052

only 128 value (read in the allocating block is correct).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Remember that in C all arguments are passed *by value*. Which means the value in the call is *copied* into the functions local argument variable. You modify the local argument variable, and as any local variables they cease to exist once the function return, making all the modifications lost. Please do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: By the way, the way you use the `ringBufferInit` function you don't even *need* the allocation call. By declaring the variable as a non-pointer object in `testRingBufferPushPopSingle` the compiler have already allocated the memory for you, like for any other local variable. And of course, since `ringBuffer` is not a pointer to a structure, but an actual structure object, `ringBuffer->capacity` is wrong and should be `ringBuffer.capacity`.

Comment: To solve your problem you need to decide what `ringBufferInit` should do: Should it *allocate* memory for the structure and initialize it? Or should it *only* initialize the structure? Right now you try to have it both ways, and that won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `ringBufferInit` does not make a sense. In the function `testRingBufferPushPopSingle` you already created an object of the type `RingBuffer`.

```
RingBuffer ringBuffer;
```

So what the function `ringBufferInit` needs to do is to initialize data members of the already created object `ringBuffer`

It can look the following way

```
static inline void ringBufferInit(RingBuffer* ringBuffer)
{
    //ringBuffer->ringBuffer = buffer;
    ringBuffer->capacity = 128;
    printf("%d \n", ringBuffer->capacity);
}
```

Otherwise within the function

```
static inline void ringBufferInit(RingBuffer* ringBuffer)
{

    ringBuffer = (RingBuffer *) malloc(sizeof(RingBuffer));

    //ringBuffer->ringBuffer = buffer;
    ringBuffer->capacity = 128;
    printf("%d \n", ringBuffer->capacity);
}
```

you changed its local variable `ringBuffer` (of the pointer type `RingBuffer *`) that will not be alive after exiting the function.